Serilog with Audit and Fallback
I have been looking for a Serilog Sink that supports AuditTo and WriteTo. To an HTTP Endpoint
The AuditTo must write immediately and throw an error if it cannot write to the HTTP endpoint  (Too many Requests or any other error)
The write to can be batched, and if a write to the endpointd doesn't succeed write the message to a queue...
I have been looking for a sink that would support Auditto and doesn't need too much rework.
The problem is that there is not that much documentation on writing sinks that support Audit to.... And the ones that do, are quite complicated.
I am looking for a very basic sample that i can extend to fit my needs.
The requirements currently are

Write to Azure Monitor
Have a collection of DCR (Data Collection Rules), and use round robin to select one.
(Write to and AuditTo have different DCR endpoints)

This is because DCR only supports 12000 requests per minute and if my Durable functions start to scale out, the many Log and Audit statements will consume those 12000 fairly quickly.
The Audit Must be successful because
